# OpenCV capturing desktop screen live

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam

I'm using OpenCV for a c++ coding project. I'm having some difficulty with some of the limitations in OpenCV, I want to analyse a video file and detect certain objects. This works perfectly, but now I want it to analyse a section of my desktop screen. (live)

Does anybody have a clue how to accomplish this? I thought of making a webcam simulator that captures my desktop screen but I think thats way to complicated and it should be much more easy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148758/how-to-capture-the-desktop-in-opencv-ie-turn-a-bitmap-into-a-mat

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm looking more for something like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7rS6bH_OHY

Comment: The link "engine" gave you is what you need (windows OS). You could limit the capturing to a subarea of the full screen later or you could capture a single window if you want to.

Comment: libvlc could be a choice too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186401/libvlc-stream-part-of-screen

Answer (score 4):

If you're targeting Windows OS, the option recommended by Engine seems ideal.

For Linux I ended up using an RTSP server(FFSERVER) as a VideoCapture input, then screencasting using FFMPEG with "x11grab".

FFMPEG for Windows will accept the "screen-capture-recorder" application as an input, but I don't have any experience setting up an RTSP server on windows.

For my setup this translated to code that looked like this:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cap.open("http://localhost:8090/live.flv"); // open the default camera
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1'));
```

and

```
cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size(200, 200));
cv::VideoWriter outStream("http://localhost:8090/feed2.ffm",
CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1'), 10, cv::Size(200, 200), true);
```

The 200x200 resolution was necessary to minimize latency so if you can grab the screen buffer directly to avoid unnecessary screencasting/encoding that sounds better from a performance standpoint...